# Does boost test have support for wide strings?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, logging, widestring

I'm just using BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(L"blah") and the only thing that is printed out is an hex value such as 0x12345678. Am I missing some configuration? I'm using boost 1.44.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [boost/test/unit_test_log.h](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/test/unit_test_log.hpp), you can see that the class unit_test_log_t is using a std::ostream for streaming the logs.
So, you will probably have to implement your own logger.